# How do I air parry?

Tags: metal-gear-rising-revengeance

I got knocked in an upwards motion by a Mastiff on the first level in Very Hard mode.   Even though as I was falling down and the Mastiff jumped up to attack me, the game went into slow mo. I thought that since this was an opportunity to air parry, I tried to use the parry technique but for some reason it didn't do anything.

Is there supposed to be a way to air parry or something?

Comment: Is it not Jump + Y/Triangle?

Comment: I'm playing the game for the first time now, and reviewing old questions for things I may have missed. I'm not 100% sure but this may be a case where you can use the Defensive Offense unlockable skill (Jump + Light Attack) to dodge. There are other enemies that have slow-mo sequences that allow you to dodge with that skill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to purchase the "Aerial Parry" skill for 3000 BP (the store opens between chapters) in order to parry in mid-air.

[image]